# How to integrate Keycloak with Spring boot with custom login form

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, keycloak

I have restful Spring Boot app with basic auth. I want to integrate Keycloak and change auth to oauth2 with jwt token (from Keycloak). So I have doubt about how to do it. With a help of oauth2 resource service(but I want my own forms for login and registration) or keycloak admin client or keycloak rest api?

It is my WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                .requestMatchers("/webhook").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/products").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/products_html").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/confirm-email").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole(String.valueOf(CustomerRole.ADMIN))
                .requestMatchers("/subscriptions/**").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/customers/**").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/profile/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated());

        http.httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(c -> c
                        .frameOptions()
                        .disable());

        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout");

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(CustomerRepository customerRepository, CustomerService mapper) {
        return email -> customerRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(email)
                .map(mapper::toUserDetails).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(email + " not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource bundleMessageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just don't write identification forms in your app. [This is not how authorization_code flow works](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials).

What you can do is styling the UI exposed by your authorisation server to users. [For Keycloak, this is documented there](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes).